# does not contain a definition for 'Form' ? Outlook Add-in

Tags: c#, visual-studio, outlook-addin

Recently I' am working on an add-in with c# for Outlook 2010 in Visual Studio 2012 . I developed a custom Form region which contains simple textboxes and a button. In Button_click method I' am taking an error (error Code : error CS0117) and I couldn't figure out why ? I am really new of this environment :) any way here it is my problem. (if you need more code to solve just let me know)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Office = Microsoft.Office.Core;
using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;
using MSForms = Microsoft.Vbe.Interop.Forms;
```

.
.
.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        // save button
        MSForms.UserForm userForm = (MSForms.UserForm) FormRegion1.Form;
        MSForms.Controls formControls = userForm.Controls;

        Outlook.OlkTextBox ad =
           (Outlook.OlkTextBox)formControls.Item("ad");
        string cariad = ad.Text;

        Outlook.OlkTextBox adres =
          (Outlook.OlkTextBox)formControls.Item("adres");
        string cariadres = adres.Text;

        Outlook.OlkTextBox vergid =
          (Outlook.OlkTextBox)formControls.Item("vergid");
        string carivergid = vergid.Text;
```

.
.
.

*`MSForms.UserForm userForm = (MSForms.UserForm)` in line `FormRegion1.Form` "Form" is not recognized. And error says

> " error CS0117: 'OutlookAddIn2.FormRegion1' does not contain a
>   definition for 'Form'".

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved that problem with not using Forms:) Simply, I just typed

```
 this.TextBoxName.Text;
```

to reach the text of the textBox. Thanks any way.